# @WebParam on a parameter of interface method - how to get name?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I try to get the name `"best_user"` of the annotation @WebParam on a method parameter `User user` in an interface method. Because it is an interface, the following code does not give me access to the annotation:

```
String methodName = "doSomething";

Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(packageName + "." + "UserService");

Method serviceMethod = null;

for (Method method: clazz.getMethods())
{
    if (method.getName().equals(methodName))
    {
        serviceMethod = method;
        break;
    }
}

Class<?>[] parameterTypes = serviceMethod.getParameterTypes();
WebParam webParam = parameterTypes[0].getAnnotation(WebParam.class); //webParam is null
String parameterName = webParam.name();
```

However the web service framework is able to get this data. How can I do it as well?

Interface:

```
@WebService(name = "UserService", targetNamespace = "my.targetNamespace")
public interface UserService {
    @WebMethod
    public String doSomething
        (
            @WebParam(name = "best_user")
            User user
        )
}
```

Comment: show me how do you obtain the Method 'method'? If you take it from the class, the annotation will not be there. You would have to get it from the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a limitation of interface types.

[`Method#getParameterTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes--) returns an array of parameter types. In your example, it simply contains a `User.class`, since your method has one parameter of type `User`.

You'll want to use [`Method#getParameterAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterAnnotations--) and get the first parameter's first annotation.

```
Annotation[][] parameterTypes = serviceMethod.getParameterAnnotations();
WebParam webParam = (WebParam) parameterTypes[0][0];
```

Since Java 8, you can also use [`Method#getParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters--) and [`Parameter#getAnnotation()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-)

```
WebParam webParam = serviceMethod.getParameters()[0].getAnnotation(WebParam.class);
```